# WordPress seems to have killed my Google Compute micro server by using too much memory

Tags: wordpress, debian, google-compute-engine

Basically I booted a micro server on Google Compute running Debian 8 Jesse and installed MySQL and Apache2 on it just to run a little test site. I'm not developing the theme myself so I don't have any code - I just uploaded a theme I got on themeforest that uses WPBakery to build the pages.

I noticed from the beginning that it was slow - which was fine because this was just a little test server so that my client can see it. I was planning to move it to their current hosting once it's done. However I started to notice that when I was doing a lot of edits it would freeze up occasionally and I would get "Out of Memory" errors in my ssh terminal. Which was again fine - it's just a test site I needed for a couple days to customize the theme. They would usually resolve themselves.

However once the server got stuck and I had to reboot it. That should have been my first sign to at least snapshot the disk. But once it came back up everything was fine and it was even noticeably faster. I figured something got out of hand in the WP backend and restarting the server solved the issue.

I used it for another day or two - then it suddenly stopped working again. But this time I couldn't connect with ssh any more. I rebooted it using the Google Compute GUI but nothing didn't work at all. The usage graph is peaked - and when I log the serial output I get this:

```
Feb 25 12:47:05 test-wrs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
```

And it outputs this about every second or every other second. When I watch the output during boot it looks like it starts shortly after Apache boots. But there's some other messages about a failure above - I'm not really sure what is causing it.

```
Feb 25 12:44:48 test-wrs systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
Feb 25 12:44:48 test-wrs systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Feb 25 12:44:48 test-wrs systemd[1]: Started Expand the root partition and filesystem on boot.
Feb 25 12:44:48 test-wrs systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
Feb 25 12:44:48 test-wrs systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 25 12:44:48 test-wrs systemd[1]: Failed to start Login Service.
Feb 25 12:44:48 test-wrs systemd[1]: Unit systemd-logind.service entered failed state.
Feb 25 12:44:48 test-wrs systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
[  OK  ] Started Permit User Sessions.
Feb 25 12:44:48 test-wrs systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start NTP daemon.
Feb 25 12:44:48 test-wrs systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
Feb 25 12:44:48 test-wrs systemd[1]: dbus.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 25 12:44:48 test-wrs systemd[1]: Unit dbus.service entered failed state.
Feb 25 12:44:49 test-wrs systemd[1]: Started Permit User Sessions.
Feb 25 12:44:49 test-wrs systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Feb 25 12:44:49 test-wrs systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service has no holdoff time, scheduling restart.
Feb 25 12:44:50 test-wrs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
Feb 25 12:44:51 test-wrs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
Feb 25 12:44:52 test-wrs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
Feb 25 12:44:54 test-wrs systemd[1]: Looping too fast. Throttling execution a little.
```

And I have no idea what to do here. I read that this is sometimes cause by overuse of memory which would correlate with the issues I had before - so I tried snapshotting the disk and booting it on a higher RAM server but it does the same thing no matter how high I set the RAM. And I can't ssh in to investigate more.

Does anyone have an idea what the issue might be or how to resolve it? I'm stuck and I'd really like to not have to start from scratch again and remake all the stuff I did before. If I can at the least get a dump of the MySQL database I'd be happy - but the database isn't configured to accept remote connections because I had no reason to do that. So I have to get into it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to why your setup goes out of memory, we can only speculate. The fact, that the issue does not disappear with a bigger VM, suggests, that this is caused by some configuration or setup issue.
You might try to run the [Wordpress setup preconfigured by Google](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/click-to-deploy-images/wordpress?), which can be found under "Deployment Manager" "Cloud Launcher". You can run them on any size of VM and from experience I can assure you that the basic installation does not go out of memory.
To recover your database, you could do the following: 
1. shut down the VM from Developers Console
2.take a snapshot of the disk
3. attach the snapshot as additional disk to a working VM (choose option: create a new disk -from snapshot)
Perform above steps in Developers Console, and do not forget to click the "save" button in the end. 
Now click the "ssh" button of the new VM and
4. mount this additional disk on the command line : 
`sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`

Note: you could do these steps from the VM you spin up via Cloud Launcher, and copy the files directly to this VM.

Comment: Mounting as an additional disk was a good idea - wish I thought of that. I seem to have been able to recover the data so thanks!